# Effects of antibiotics on bacterial growth

Tags: bacteriology

I will do an experiment on effects of antibiotics on antibacterial growth and I will use three antibiotics: ampicilin, chloramphenicol and streptomycin. To make a hypothesis I must have a guess on which antibiotic will have the most severe effect on bacteria. So, do you know any source to find this information out or I would appreciate if you explain the reasoning behind a comparison of how severe these antibiotics.

Edit: Bacteria that will be used is E.coli.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without specifying what bacteria, and even so most antibiotics will not be effective against all bacteria of the same species (due to resistance). All these antibiotics are broad-spectrum and will have a "severe effect" on some types of bacteria.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: I mean, theoritically which one is the most harmful?

Comment: The dose makes the poison.

Comment: @MarchHo - Not necessarily.

Comment: There is no previous research i guess

Comment: @BobSacamano there is research on this. Look for minimum inhibitory concentration (MIC) and LD50 values for these antibiotics. I hope your *E.coli* strain is not naturally resistant to either of these. Is it a lab strain such as K-12 or DH5a?

Comment: What would you recommend